# Download a file from sharepoint using curl

Tags: curl, sharepoint

I'm trying to download a file from sharepoint in a Linux environment using curl. I'm using curl NTLM and my request looks like below

```
curl -vvv "http://sitename/sites/site1/_layouts/15/xlviewer.aspx?id=/sites/cloud/Shared%20Documents/Export_9_26.xlsx" --ntlm --user "username":"pass" -o download.csv
```

I'm unable to download the file itself the request returns an html response

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">   
...
<script type="text/javascript"> 
... 
"           <noscript class=""ewa-root-noscript"">" 
"               Unable to load because JavaScript is disabled.  Enable JavaScript and try again."   
"           </noscript>"    
"           <div id=""ewaContainer"" class=""ewaContainer"">"   

</html>
```

What am I doing wrong and is there a better way to get around this

Answer (score 1):

The `sites/site1/_layouts/15/xlviewer.aspx` URL is the online Excel viewer, i.e. it denotes a web page, not a file. The correct URL denoting a file looks like this:

```
sites/site1/Shared%20Documents/Export_9_26.xlsx
```

where the `Shared%20Documents` denotes the document library and the rest is the path and file name.

Comment: Thanks - this explains the response